# Handle data from several activities in one onActivityResult()?

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I wonder if it's possible to handle data from e.g. activity 2 and activity 3 in activity 1 that have one `onActivityResult()`, or do I need to have one method for each activity that return data?

Activity 1 is the main activity for the application.

Activity 1:

```
// Handle return value from activity
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        String imageId = data.getExtras().getString("imageId");

        // Do something if data return from activity 2 ??

        // Do something if data return from activity 3 ??
    }
}
```

Activity 2

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("imageId", imagePath);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent); 
finish();
```

Activity 3

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("contactId", data);
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

Comment: that's what requestCode is for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

set requestCode in your `startActivityForResult` for activity 1:

**calling activity 2**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity2.class);
startActivityForResult(intent,10);
```

**calling activity 3**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, Activity3.class);
startActivityForResult(intent,11);
```

Now when you come to `onActivityResult` check that `requestCode`

like:

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
 {

      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

       switch (requestCode) {

          case (10): 
          {
            // do this if request code is 10.
          }
          break;

          case (11):
          {
            // do this if request code is 11.
          }
          break;
  }
```

Comment: Is super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data); necessary?

Comment: Derived classes must call through to the super class's implementation of this method. If they do not, an exception will be thrown.

Comment: In general (not specifically in Android stuff), when you derive, you should call through to the superclass's methods unless you know you shouldn't. It's a decision that needs to be case-by-case, but the default (I'd say) would be that you do it.

Answer (score 7):

`No confusion check result code and request code`..

Example :

```
private static final int TWO = 2;
private static final int THREE = 3;

startActivityForResult(new Intent(this,Activity2.class),TWO); // one for Activity 2
startActivityForResult(new Intent(this,Activity3.class),THREE);
```

and

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK ) {
        if(requestCode == TWO) {
            // Activity two stuff
        } else if(requestCode == THREE) {
            // Activity three stuff
        }
    }
}
```